# Can I change how many spaces 'column -t' outputs between columns?

Tags: sed, awk

`column -t` is amazing with one nit:  How can I change how many spaces are output between columns?  I want one.  `column -t` gives two.  For example,

```
echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | column -t
```

outputs

```
111  22   3
4    555  66
```

but I would like it to output the following:

```
111 22  3
4   555 66
```

I think I could run the output through sed regex to turn two spaces followed by a word boundary into a single space, but I'd like to avoid adding another tool to the mix unless its necessary.

Suggestions?  Simple replacement commands that I could use instead of `column -t` which accomplish the same thing?  Playing OFS games with awk doesn't seem like a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the builtin spacing of `column`. This leaves you with either switching to a different tool or post-processing. You can accomplish the ladder cheaply with `sed` to remove a single space before each number:

```
echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | column -t | sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
111 22  3
4   555 66
```

Comment: I like it, though I'll use a regex without a capture depending upon a generic word boundary: `echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | column -t | sed 's/ \<//g'`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from `column` to `pr` might be a good idea. `pr` has a whole lot more options for controlling output formatting, and can create columns as well...

For example:

```
echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | tr ' ' '\n' | pr -3aT -s' '
```

produces:

```
111 22 3
4 555 66
```

Not sure how to keep the alignment while still reducing the spaces, so it's not perfect.

The `tr` is in there because `pr` expects each entry on a single line.

Comment: From looking at the man page, it seems using `pr` requires knowing the number of columns and that the number of columns remains uniform throughout the input.  Is that the case?

Comment: It's more that `pr` takes a list of lines and pastes <n> of them into columns, where you specify what <n> is. That's the reason for the `tr` bit in the answer above - to break existing columns into separate lines.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear-- the pr approach doesn't seem to handle lines with an inconsistent number of columns and differs from column -t in that respect.  Short of using two passes of awk (one to count maximum columns and one to pad shorter lines) I'm not sure how to extend your pr suggestion to replace column -t.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use `tabs`. In your output you are expecting a tab number of 5. So, in terminal type: `tabs 5`. This will change the tab-width to 5.

Then type:

```
echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | tr ' ' '\t'
```

or:

```
echo -en '111\t22\t3\n4\t555\t66\n'
```

Results:

```
111 22  3
4   555 66
```

For more info, type: `man tabs`

Comment: Does this, or combining this with expand(1), permit columns of varying length like column -t?

Comment: @RhysUlerich: AFAIK, `expand` simply converts tabs to spaces. `column -t` is intuitive, whereas `tabs` uses a set tab-width. For 'pretty' output, you'll need to set a tab-width greater than the largest length of a column or columns. Note that you can set multiple tab-widths, if required. See _explicit lists_ under the `tabs` man page. For example, `tabs 10,+20` will space the second column 10 spaces from the start of the line and the third column will be spaced 30 spaces from the start of the line. So, `tabs` can handle varying lengths, just not automatically/intuitively like `column -t`. HTH.

Comment: Reading your description and then the man pages, I think piping the output through `tr` then `expand --tabs=LIST` (where the `LIST` of tab stops is based on the maximum lengths found in each column) gives the closed thing to the output of `column -t`.  That's perfectly doable, but it requires a nonlinear pipeline.

Comment: @RhysUlerich: Exactly why are you using `expand`? The pipeline is completely linear without it. It's also much less wasteful and dangerous compared to a pipe to `column -t` and or `sed`. The only overhead is a simple translation of your delimiter (a single space) to a tab.

Comment: I'd like to use `expand` because I would like the resulting output to, like `column -t`, to not contain tabs.

Answer (score 0):

column now has an option to define that spacing.

```
column --help
  -o, --output-separator <string>  columns separator for table output (default is two spaces)
```

single space delimited

```
echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | column -t -o ' '
111 22  3
4   555 66
```

and pipe delimited

```
echo -en '111 22 3\n4 555 66\n' | column -t -o '|'
111|22 |3
4  |555|66
```